# ReactJS and Google Places problems in IE9

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internet-explorer-9, google-places-api

I am using Google Places in my ReactJS application and IE9 has problems with the way I'm doing this:

```
Error: only call this function after the script has in fact loaded.
```

(that's on the first line in places.js)

Later IE versions have no problems (nor has other browsers).

The way I'm loading my Google stuff is that I'm using the ReactScriptLoader.

```
var ReactScriptLoaderModule = require('../utils/ReactScriptLoader.js');
var ReactScriptLoaderMixin= ReactScriptLoaderModule.ReactScriptLoaderMixin;
var ReactScriptLoader= ReactScriptLoaderModule.ReactScriptLoader;
var googleMapsURL = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.21.10&libraries=places&callback=initializeGoogleAPI';

window.initializeGoogleAPI = function() {
    ReactScriptLoader.triggerOnScriptLoaded(googleMapsURL);
}
```

This happens in my main App.jsx, before anything else happens. The callback ensures the dispatcher will tell the application Google is ready.

```
onScriptLoaded: function(){ AppActions.googleScriptsLoaded(); },
```

I suspect how that is handled is irrelevant here, just want to show what's going on and how I'm thinking with the loading of the script. What I'm thinking is that maybe something happens before the window is completely loaded, or something?

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

In general, my advice is now to avoid the ReactScriptLoader. It's a promising effort, but requires some bug fixes and some better docs. The problem is that calls of the sort:

```
window.initializeGoogleAPI = function() {
ReactScriptLoader.triggerOnScriptLoaded(googleMapsURL);
}
```

may happen before the component, which does all the map stuff, is even loaded. And since React frowns on putting JavaScript+script tags in other places such is within JSX, you may have a concurrency problem on your hands, and not just in IE9.

There are <strike>two</strike> three ways out:

1. Read what these guys did. Ignore the CoffeeScript stuff: 
   http://revelry.co/development/2015/02/19/react-google-maps/
2. Read this on refs http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html
3. Read about the simple LoadJS hack on reddit (third comment): https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/37mm70/how_to_render_a_script_tag_in_a_component/

Good luck!